# How can I check if a function is strictly quasi-concave or quasi-concave?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm currently learning how to solve constrained maximisation problems. More specifically, since I have to follow the steps provided by my professor, I have to find out if the solution to a maximisation problem - if any - is unique, before working on the Kuhn-Tucker conditions.

Let $\mathcal{f}:\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{g}:\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the objective function and the constraint function respectively. Let X $\subseteq$ $\mathbb{R^3}$ be $\mathcal{f}$'s and $\mathcal{g}$'s domain.

Here is what he's written (I re-arranged some things to make it shorter for you to read):

> We know that the solution to the problem, if any, is unique if:
>
> $\langle\mathcal{f}$ is strictly quasi-concave $\land$ $\mathcal{g}$ is quasi-concave$\rangle$ $\bigvee$ $\langle\mathcal{g}$ is strictly quasi-concave $\land$ $\mathcal{f}$ is quasi-concave and locally non-satiated $\vee$ $\mathcal{f}$ is affine and non constant $\vee$ $\mathcal{f}$ is quasi-concave and strictly monotone $\vee$ $\mathcal{f}$ is quasi-concave and $\forall$ *x* $\in$ X, D$\mathcal{f}$(*x*) $\gg$ 0 $\vee$ $\mathcal{f}$ is quasi-concave and $\forall$ *x* $\in$ X, D$\mathcal{f}$(*x*) $\ll$ 0$\rangle$

**My main question is:** how can I check if *e.g.* $\mathcal{f}$ is strictly quasi-concave and $\mathcal{g}$ is quasi-concave, using the Hessian matrix?

**My preliminary answer:** I'd try to check if *e.g.* $\mathcal{f}$ is strictly concave ($\implies$ strictly quasi-concave) and, if it was so, I'd proceed to check if $\mathcal{g}$ is pseudo-concave ($\implies$ quasi-concave), or vice-versa. The same goes for the other "part" of the quoted conditions, should the one I've just used as an example not be verified.
What am I missing? Is there a more direct method to check strict-quasi-concavity and quasi-concavity using the Hessian?

**What I know:**

- *strict concavity* $\implies$ *concavity* $\implies$ *pseudo concavity* $\implies$ *quasi concavity*.
- *strict concavity* $\implies$ *differentiable-strict-quasi-concavity*.
- Lastly, I know how to use the Hessian to check if a function is strictly concave, concave or quasi-concave.

Comment: Generally speaking, I don't think knowledge of the Hessian can guarantee anything about the quasi-concavity of a function. E.g., both $e^x$ and $\sqrt{x}$ are quasiconcave and have opposite sign Hessians.

It is certainly true that if you can show your functions are concave, then they will be quasiconcave. But this is simply because all concave functions are quasiconcave, and you wouldn't be able to guarantee that this method would catch all quasiconcave functions.

Comment: @EdwardChien According to my professor's book, which cites a theorem by Simon (1985), you can say that your function is pseudo concave (so it would also be quasi-concave) if, given a C2 function from Rn to R, _n_ greater or equal than 2, _k_ ranging from 3 to _n_ + 1, **the sign of the k-leading principal minor of the Hessian is equal to the sign of (-1)^(k-1)**. I guess my doubt is more about "what do I make of my original question if the function isn't pseudo concave, and therefore I can't show its quasi-concavity?"

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't a general approach for this; all approaches are ad-hoc. The only thing you can do is go back to first principles, ie, check if the definition holds, ie, $f$ is quasi-concave iff $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\geq\min\{f(x),f(y)\}~\forall~x,y\in\textrm{Dom }f~\land~\lambda\in [0,1]$

Comment: ^ ... 
this is not to say that this will be tractable for all functions $f$; you can see [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/characterisations-of-quasiconvex-functions/9E4B155E5FA081A28F2E4E3897E08063) that showing quasi-convexity (equivalently quasi-concavity for its negative map) for just a particular class of functions (lower semicontinuous function on an infinite dimensional space) is enough for a research paper.

Comment: @RiccardoRomei Yeah, the counterexample suggests that there's no equivalent statement that only references properties of the Hessian. The linked paper from Prasun finds equivalence with quasimonotonicity of the Clarke-Rockafellar subdifferential for a pretty large class of functions (lower semi-continuous). But yeah...that's not a Hessian (closer to a gradient or directional derivative).